# unexpected behavior in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, eclipse-luna

I am just creating simple program

```
package kumar

object testing {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  }
}
```

Hitting with following error when I tried to save the program

Syntax error on tokens, ClassHeader expected instead - on package line kumar

Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Syntax error on token "String", delete this token

Syntax error on token ":", delete this token

Errors are disappeared when i give project clean build. Whenever i tried to save the program,again i m hitting with above error .Any help please

Note - I am using eclipse neon.Have tried mvn eclipse:eclipse ,clean install

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not really familiar with kumar but the error seems to be coming from your package import. I suggest making sure the package is imported correctly before moving on to the code.

Comment: i just created one package in my project thats it ...ok will leave the package still i m getting following error Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Syntax error on token "String", delete this token

Syntax error on token ":", delete this token